# how take father from button click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to get father after a click: i have this code html:

```
 <button mat-icon-button (click)="download($event)">
```

the code html generate is this:

```
  <button _ngcontent-wsc-c153="" mat-icon-button="" class="" aria-label="">
    <mat-icon _ngcontent-wsc-c153="" role="img" alt="download" class="" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-2" cdk-describedby-host="0">download_for_offline</mat-icon><!---->
</button>
```

in my ts file I do this:

```
 download(event) {
   
    console.log(event);
```

How I can get from event the father because `event.target` is `mat-icon` but I need get the father button?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
download(event) {
  const parentButton = event.target.parentNode;
  console.log(parentButton);
}
```

*Note: The term "father" is not commonly used in web development to refer to the parent element. Use the term "parent" instead.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement).

```js
download(event) {
  console.log(event);
  const parent = event.target.parentElement; //parent button
}
```